# Get the return values from another function - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get the values from this function, so, when i call that function "prompt" a send a message and this function return an value according with the supposed question that i made.

But i can't receive that value, so why ?
I'm noob with haskell.

```
module Main (main) where
import System.IO (stdout, hSetBuffering, BufferMode(NoBuffering))
type State = Double

main::IO()
prompt::Read a =>  String ->  IO a


main = do putStrLn "Testing"
          v <- prompt "Whats your name?"
          return ()

prompt str = do putStrLn str
                valor <- readLn
                return valor
```

Comment: Presumably, you want `v` to be of type `String`, but the compiler has no way of knowing that.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem, I believe, is confined to your type signatures.

```
prompt :: Read a => String -> IO a
```

This type signature says that `prompt` is a function which takes a string, does some I/O magic, and then returns a value of type `a`, for *any* readable type `a` the user wishes. However, your implementation gets a string from the user and returns it.

If your intention is that `prompt` return a string, simply change your type.

```
prompt :: Read a => String -> IO a
```

If your intention truly is that `prompt` return a value of some arbitrary user-specified type, you need to resolve the ambiguity when you actually read the value.

```
prompt :: Read a => String -> IO a
prompt str = do putStrLn str
                valor <- readLn
                return valor
```

You'll get an ambiguity error in `main`, since Haskell can't figure out what type you want `v` to be. This can be resolved by explicitly specifying.

```
v <- prompt "Whats your name?" :: IO String
```

(or, equivalently, `IO Int` for an integer, `IO Double` for a double, or any other readable type)

However, more than likely you intended that `prompt` always return a string. So I recommend the first solution, as it will be more intuitive to users.

Comment: The `read valor` step is redundant. `readLn` already has type `Read a => IO a`

Comment: @4castle I learned something today then. I don't think I've ever used `readLn` for anything other than strings. Thanks for the correction! :)

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of `getLine`? It *does* have type `IO String`